# permanently change permissions of linux system file

Tags: linux, permissions

I often use my computer in text-only mode, so no X11, no window manager, etc. I'd like to be able to adjust the screen brightness of my laptop while in text mode, which I can do by writing to the file

`/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

In order to write to the file, I either run the command through `sudo` or change the permissions for the `brightness` file.

I'd like to write a script which will change the brightness by increments, for which I would need permanent write access to the `brightness` file. Unfortunately, since it's in `/sys`, it's generated dynamically every time I boot up, so I need to change the file's permissions every time I restart.

I gather that I can change the permissions permanently by writing a `udev` rule, which I've never done before. Would that be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do, or is there a safer alternative? For example, putting something in `rc.local`, using `cron`, etc.

Comment: `udev` rules are more complex than a single `echo` command in `rc.local`. You seem to already know the answer to your own question, more or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `rc.local` method simply because it is easier and simpler than writing and maintaining a custom `udev` rule. You might also have to write a script that re-applies the permissions upon resuming from suspend and hibernation. Such script should be put in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` (requires `pm-utils`), if needed.